# Qt Cryptographic Architecture - Qt 5.2

Tags: c++, qt

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/JPNaude/dev_notes/wiki/Using-the-Qt-Cryptographic-Architecture-with-Qt5 (Windows)
I have installed: OpenSSL-1_0_1h, CMake 3.0.0 and Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010), (I tested also on 2.8.12.2 - no change)
But after "make" i executed also "make install", because there wasn't files qca(d).dll and qca-ossl(d).dll
Now in my project i added in .pro file CONFIG   += crypto
QtCrypto library is detected, but if i want for example generate RSA private key, it throws some issues

```
QCA::PrivateKey sessionKey = QCA::KeyGenerator().createRSA(1024);
```

When compiling in release mode:
"cannot find -lqca"

When compiling in debug mode:

> undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3QCA12KeyGeneratorC1EP7QObject'
>
> undefined reference to
>   `_imp___ZN3QCA12KeyGenerator9createRSAEiiRK7QString'
>
> undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3QCA12KeyGeneratorD1Ev'
>
> undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3QCA10PrivateKeyD1Ev'
>
> undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3QCA12KeyGeneratorD1Ev'
>
> undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3QCA10PrivateKeyD1Ev'

edit:
If you're using CONFIG += crypto like me, you have to change LINKAGE line in crypto.prf from -lqca to destination of libqca.dll (in my example: LINKAGE = E:\crypto\libqca.dll)

Comment: If you add `-L/*PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB*/ -lqca` in your .pro file, does it solve your problem ? Have you qca.dll ?

Comment: in /lib/qca/crypto i have: libqca-gnupg.dll, libqca-logger.dll, libqca-ossl.dll and libqca-softstore.dll. No there is no qca.dll

Comment: In the readme, I saw `qca(d).dll is placed in /src`. If you have it, you can either put all your needed dll's in the same folder or change `/*PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB*/`.

Comment: But there is no qca(d).dll, i made mistake, error is "cannot find -lqcad". What is lqcad? Is it part of QCad? Here is my tree of all files: http://pastebin.com/Ztyiep95

Comment: When you compile with external libraries, you must specify where to find your library using `-L/*PATH*/` and which library to be linked with `-l/*LIB_NAME*/`. The lib name is without the prefix 'lib' and without the extension. Seeing all of your files, I have found `libqca.dll` in bin folder (l.38 in pastebin). So try to add `-L/*PATH_TO_BIN*/ -lqca`.

Comment: Tried LIBS += E:\crypto -lqca, LIBS += -LE:\crypto -lqca, LIBS += -LE:\crypto\ -lqca, LIBS += -LE:\crypto\libqca.dll, LIBS += -LE:\crypto\libqca.dll -lqca AND still got cannot find -lqca

Comment: I have repaired this, LINKAGE in crypto.prf was wrong. It can't be just -lqca, it must be destination of lib (in my example: LINKAGE = E:\crypto\libqca.dll). Thx for help :)